# performance issue for intermediate merge/join dataframes to compute stats

Tags: python, performance, pandas, merge

I have a dataframe that is comprised of city airport combination pairs from a total universe of ~4000 airports. The number of combinations is in the millions but I work with a subset of the data which is approximately 1.5 million pairs (rows of df_pairs).

**df_pairs:**

```
    city1   city2
    0   sfo yyz
    1   sfo yvr
    2   sfo dfw
    3   sfo ewr
    4   sfo pdx
```

**output of df_pairs.to_dict('records'):**

```
[{'index': 0, 'city1': 'sfo', 'city2': 'yyz'},
 {'index': 1, 'city1': 'sfo', 'city2': 'yvr'},
 {'index': 2, 'city1': 'sfo', 'city2':'dfw'},
 {'index': 3, 'city1': 'sfo', 'city2':'ewr'},
 {'index': 4, 'city1': 'sfo', 'city2': 'pdx'}]
```

For each city pair (row) in the `df_pairs`, I want to perform various pair level computations.

I have 3 additional dataframes that hold various numerical and categorical  information about each airport.

They look like something like (although some dfs are monthly data and others daily data):

**df_stats1:**

```
city    fuel    landings    takeoffs    passengers
date                    
2014-05-01  sfo 2.32    4.26    4.87    6.58
2014-05-01  yyz 14.00   1.50    20.00   5.00
2014-05-01  yvr 24.78   2.90    50.55   6.64
2014-05-01  dfw 2.40    4.06    4.06    6.54
2014-05-01  ewr 30.35   9.96    64.24   6.66
2014-05-01  pdx 60.35   5.45    4.12    6.98
```

**Output of df_stats1.reset_index().to_dict('records'):**

```
[{'date': Timestamp('2014-05-01 00:00:00'),
  'city': 'sfo',
  'landings': 4.26,
  'passengers': 6.58,
  'fuel': 2.32,
  'takeoffs': 4.87},
 {'date': Timestamp('2014-05-01 00:00:00'),
  'city': 'yyz',
  'landings': 1.5,
  'passengers': 5.00,
  'fuel': 14.00,
  'takeoffs': 20.00},
 {'date': Timestamp('2014-05-01 00:00:00'),
  'city': 'yvr',
  'landings': 2.9,
  'passengers': 6.64,
  'fuel': 24.78,
  'takeoffs': 50.55},
 {'date': Timestamp('2014-05-01 00:00:00'),
  'city': 'dfw',
  'landings': 4.06,
  'passengers': 6.54,
  'fuel': 2.4,
  'takeoffs': 4.06},
 {'date': Timestamp('2014-05-01 00:00:00'),
  'city': 'ewr',
  'landings': 9.96,
  'passengers': 6.66,
  'fuel': 30.35,
  'takeoffs': 64.24},
  {'date': Timestamp('2014-05-01 00:00:00'),
  'city': 'pdx',
  'landings': 5.45,
  'passengers': 6.98,
  'fuel': 60.35,
  'takeoffs': 4.12}]
```

Now, I have a function `calstats` that is executed by:

```
df_pairs.apply(calstats, axis=1, args=(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7, blah blah))
```

The first thing `calcstats` function does is to construct 3 intermediate/temporary dataframes by selecting the data for each city in the pair from the stat dfs and aligning them side by side in a row by performing a `merge`.

**Example of one of the intermediate/temp dfs:**

```
city1_df = df_stats1[df_stats1['city'] == row['city1']]
city2_df = df_stats1[df_stats1['city'] == row['city2']]   

tmp_city_pair_df = city1_df.merge(city2_df, left_index=True, right_index=True, how = 'right', suffixes=('_1','_2'))
```

I then use the 3 intermediate/temp dfs (i.e. tmp_city_pair_df) to perform various computations like the difference between landings between the pairs, the max(of this difference in the time period under question), min() etc.

I have various performance issues that arise.

The first is that the total time required to construct the 3 intermediate dfs is approximately: `0:00:00.048481`.

I have approximately `1.5` million rows in `df_pairs` so the total cost to perform the intermediate dfs is `1,500,000 x 0:00:00.048481` = `72,721.5` seconds = `20.2` hours.

So it takes `20` hours just to construct the intermediate dfs and does not include the time cost required to use those intermediate dfs in performing further computations.

I'm wondering whether there is a more efficient way to do this.

Essentially, what I'm doing is a lookup of `city1` and `city2` in `df_stats1`, `df_stats2` and `df_stats3` and constructing intermediate/temporary dfs which I can work with to perform pair level computations.

**UPDATE**

I wanted to provide additional information.

So, the intent is to produce a final dataframe on a pair basis that looks something like the following, which I can use for further processing.

```
city1   city2   stat1, stat2, stat3, stat4, stat5, stat6 ...
    0   sfo yyz, x, x, x, x, x, x
    1   sfo yvr, y, y, y, y, y, y
    2   sfo dfw, z, z, z, z, z, z
    3   sfo ewr, a, a, a, a, a, a 
    4   sfo pdx, b, b, b, b, b, b
```

The statistics named stat1 through stat6 above are proprietary statistics that do not exist in the raw data.

The raw data is comprised of 3 dataframes, which I call:

```
df_stat1
df_stat2
df_stat3
```

`df_stat1` = daily data (fuel, landings, takeoffs, passengers) for each airport for the past 24 months

`df_stat2` = `df_stat1` but aggregated to the month (via `df.stat1.groupby(['city',pd.TimeGrouper('M')]`

`df_stat3` = monthly data time series for each airport for the past 24 months that comprises information such as landing fees, revenue etc

Now, to get to the final dataframe various computations need to take place. I want to compute things like:

```
1) City1 Landings - City2 Landings (on a daily and monthly basis)
2) Sign of statistic in #1 (positive or negative)
```

So for example, in the final dataframe, `stat1` could be:

Sum of ONLY positive values in #2 above.

So you can see that various operations need to occur to arrive at the final dataframe.

I'm not sure how I can do this to best utilize pandas/python's vectorization capabilities.

For example, to produce the Sum of ONLY positive values in #2 above, I would need to join daily data time series (from df_stat1) for each city pair, compute the subtraction between City1 landings and City2 landings and then Sum the positive values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python (and pandas) have bad performance when it comes to constructing a large number of objects. Your `merge` for each row in an `apply` does just that. Instead, you might try the following:

```
tmp = pd.merge(df_pairs, df_stats.add_suffix('_1'), left_on='city1', right_on='city_1', how='left')

pd.merge(tmp, df_stats.add_suffix('_2'), left_on='city2', right_on='city_2', how='left')
```

This will *first* perform the merge, effectively (the two-line construction here is in order to save space, and do the merge just on all pairs in `df_pairs`).

Moreover, you can now do all your analysis vectorically, which should be much faster in any case. If you add more details regarding the analysis you want, then this can be addressed further.

**Edit**

Based on edits to the question and comments, here is an outline of dealing with daily data. Specifically, let's deal with daily differences in landing dates (which you can adapt for all sorts of variations, e.g., only positive differences).

Say you start with

```
landings_by_date = df_stats1[['city', 'date', 'landings']].set_index(['city', 'date']).unstack()
landings_by_date.columns = landings_by_date.columns.get_level_values(1)
```

To find the differences in landing dates for a specific date, say the first one (index 0), you can do

```
lhs = pd.merge(df_pairs, landings_by_date.ix[:, [0]], left_on='city1', right_index=True, how='left').set_index(['city1', 'city2'])
rhs = pd.merge(df_pairs, landings_by_date.ix[:, [0]], left_on='city2', right_index=True, how='left').set_index(['city1', 'city2'])
lhs - rhs
```

(or, to drop to numpy,

```
(lhs - rhs).values
```

)

To calculate some aggregate for all dates, perform this on a loop (so that the date index is 0, 1, ...), and update the aggregate.

Why should this be more efficient? According to the specifics in your problem, there are ~3000 daily dates, but ~1.5e6 rows.

1. Even though you're looping (which is frowned upon in numerical Python), you're doing it for only ~3000 iterations, and vectorially crunching ~1.5e6 entries in each iteration.
2. You're not creating small DataFrames ~1.5e6 times (as in your question), you're creating (larger) DataFrames only ~3000 times.
3. The memory requirements should be tiny - just an extra ~1.5e6 per aggregate.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. Before I provide additional details, I wanted to mention that one of the df_stats is comprised of a time series of daily data of 4 columns for the past 24 months. So if we merge that to the df_pairs for both cities we get roughly ~730x4x2 (365x2 years x 4 columns x 2 cities) columns per row?

Comment: @codingknob It's a bit hard to address this without the specifics. Obviously, it would be best if for your calculations you could condense this to statistics taking less than ~3000 items. This is either possible or not (depending on what you want to do with pairs of this data). If not, and this is too large to fit into memory, then perhaps it would be better to apply my suggestion in *chunks* (your solution is also based on chunks, just with the extreme value that the chunks size = 1).

Comment: Ami, Thanks for the comment. I have provided additional information as an UPDATE to my question. Please feel free to request any additional information as you see fit. I kindly appreciate your help.

Comment: @codingknob See update. I'm actually a bit curious how this works out for you.

Comment: Ami, thank you for the solution. I truly appreciate it. I am currently trying it out. Will provide further details on how I made out in the next few days.

Comment: Ami, instead of the for loop, theres an easier way as described in the solution in this question I posted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38906297/operation-with-non-existing-dataframes/38907008#38907008

Comment: @codingknob Not sure what you mean. I was under the impression that the suggested solution there would not fit into your memory. If it does, great (in fact, it's pretty similar to what I suggested above originally). The loops I suggested were just meant to help you conserve space.