# += operation with non existing dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

**df_pairs:**

```
city1   city2
0   sfo yyz
1   sfo yvr
2   sfo dfw
3   sfo ewr
```

**output of df_pairs.to_dict('records'):**

```
[{'city1': 'sfo', 'city2': 'yyz'},
 {'city1': 'sfo', 'city2': 'yvr'},
 {'city1': 'sfo', 'city2': 'dfw'},
 {'city1': 'sfo', 'city2': 'ewr'}]
```

**data_df:**

```
    city    2016-02-02 00:00:00 2016-02-05 00:00:00 2016-02-01 00:00:00 2016-02-04 00:00:00 2016-02-03 00:00:00
0   sfo -33.63  -62.34  -35.70  -31.84  -33.87
1   yyz -24.31  -51.17  -22.07  -31.00  -23.00
2   yvr -24.31  -51.17  -22.07  -31.00  -23.00
3   dfw -32.17  -43.77  -34.84  0.27    -11.49
4   ewr -28.87  -59.66  -28.40  -32.94  -29.06
```

**output of data_df.to_dict('records')**

```
[{'city': 'sfo',
  Timestamp('2016-02-02 00:00:00'): -33.63,
  Timestamp('2016-02-05 00:00:00'): -62.34,
  Timestamp('2016-02-01 00:00:00'): -35.7,
  Timestamp('2016-02-04 00:00:00'): -31.84,
  Timestamp('2016-02-03 00:00:00'): -33.87},
 {'city': 'yyz',
  Timestamp('2016-02-02 00:00:00'): -24.31,
  Timestamp('2016-02-05 00:00:00'): -51.17,
  Timestamp('2016-02-01 00:00:00'): -22.07,
  Timestamp('2016-02-04 00:00:00'): -31.0,
  Timestamp('2016-02-03 00:00:00'): -23.0},
 {'city': 'yvr',
  Timestamp('2016-02-02 00:00:00'): -24.31,
  Timestamp('2016-02-05 00:00:00'): -51.17,
  Timestamp('2016-02-01 00:00:00'): -22.07,
  Timestamp('2016-02-04 00:00:00'): -31.0,
  Timestamp('2016-02-03 00:00:00'): -23.0},
 {'city': 'dfw',
  Timestamp('2016-02-02 00:00:00'): -32.17,
  Timestamp('2016-02-05 00:00:00'): -43.77,
  Timestamp('2016-02-01 00:00:00'): -34.84,
  Timestamp('2016-02-04 00:00:00'): 0.27,
  Timestamp('2016-02-03 00:00:00'): -11.49},
 {'city': 'ewr',
  Timestamp('2016-02-02 00:00:00'): -28.87,
  Timestamp('2016-02-05 00:00:00'): -59.66,
  Timestamp('2016-02-01 00:00:00'): -28.4,
  Timestamp('2016-02-04 00:00:00'): -32.94,
  Timestamp('2016-02-03 00:00:00'): -29.06}]
```

So I have a df named `df_pairs`. For every pair in `df_pairs`, I want to lookup city1 and city2 in `data_df`, subtract one from the other, take the sign of the difference time series, separate positive and negative sign values, separate positive and negative difference values and calculate sums on each across the columns of data_df.

```
diff_df_sign_pos = diff_df_sign_neg = diff_df_pos = diff_df_neg = 0

for i in range(0,len(data_df.columns)):
    a = pd.merge(df_pairs[['city1','city2']], data_df.ix[:, [i]], left_on='city1', right_index=True, how='left').set_index(['city1', 'city2'])
    b = pd.merge(df_pairs[['city1','city2']], data_df.ix[:, [i]], left_on='city2', right_index=True, how='left').set_index(['city1', 'city2'])
    diff_df = b - a
    diff_df_sign = np.sign(diff_df)
    diff_df_sign_pos+= diff_df_sign.clip(lower=0)
    diff_df_sign_neg+= diff_df_sign.clip(upper=0)
    diff_df_pos+= diff_df.clip(lower=0)
    diff_df_neg+= diff_df.clip(upper=0)
```

If you run the above code, you will see that the final values for `diff_df_sign_pos`, `diff_df_sign_neg`, `diff_df_pos` and `diff_df_neg` are NaN's.

For example, the end result for `diff_df_sign_pos` should look like:

```
               2016-02-03 00:00:00
city1    city2  
sfo      yyz    5.0
         yvr    5.0
         dfw    5.0
         ewr    4.0
```

This tells us that all 5 of the differences between yyz, yvr, dfw and sfo were positive.

Comment: Also, this line `diff_df_sign_pos = diff_df_sign_neg = diff_df_pos = diff_df_neg = 0` is causing the problem. All 4 variables point to the same space in the memory. That won't work in your case, would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply do this:

```
df_city1 = pd.merge(df_pairs['city1'], data_df, left_on='city1', right_on='city', how='left')
df_city2 = pd.merge(df_pairs['city2'], data_df, left_on='city2', right_on='city', how='left')
diff = df_city2.subtract(df_city1, fill_value=0)
pos_sum = diff[diff >= 0].sum(axis=1)
neg_sum = diff[diff <  0].sum(axis=1)
```

Instead of looping over all your columns, merging 2*(number of columns) times, not to mention indexing, then that complicated bit with `np.sign` and `.clip`... Your `df_pairs` and `data_df` have a one-to-one correspondence, right?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by one-to-one correspondence? Every city in the df_pairs will exist in data_df and will have the same number of data points in its time series as every city in data_df if that is what you are asking

Comment: That there is a unique relation between the two dataframes. There is one and only one row in data_df for each row in df_pairs.

Comment: No. data_df = data on the universe of cities. df_pairs = pairs of cities from the universe. There are 2 rows in data_df for every row in df_pairs. For example, look at the data. A pair has 2 cities and the data for those cities will exist in 2 different rows in data_df.

Comment: Understood. My answer should work just fine. Did you try it?

Comment: Yup. Works great. Thank you Kartik. I appreciate it. I'm sure though that I will have further questions as I continue with this project. :)

Comment: Happy to help. I am here mainly for the challenge of solving tricky problems. Bring 'em on! 

Comment: Isn't that the first version I posted? Except for `'city2'` in the second `merge` statement...

Answer (score 0):

Give this a run:

Take out the initial variables, and get rid of the for loop.

```
a = pd.merge(df_pairs, data_df, left_on='city1', right_on='city', how='left').set_index(['city1', 'city2'])
b = pd.merge(df_pairs, data_df, left_on='city2', right_on='city', how='left').set_index(['city1', 'city2'])
del a['city']
del b['city']
```

Now do each calculation once and sum across each row (axis=1)

```
diff_df = b - a
diff_df_sign = np.sign(diff_df)
diff_df_sign_pos = diff_df_sign.clip(lower=0).sum(axis=1)
diff_df_sign_neg = diff_df_sign.clip(upper=0).sum(axis=1)
diff_df_pos = diff_df.clip(lower=0).sum(axis=1)
diff_df_neg = diff_df.clip(upper=0).sum(axis=1)
```

Does this look like this output you want?

```
city1  city2
sfo    yyz      5
       yvr      5
       dfw      5
       ewr      4
dtype: float64

city1  city2
sfo    yyz      0
       yvr      0
       dfw      0
       ewr     -1
dtype: float64

city1  city2
sfo    yyz      45.83
       yvr      45.83
       dfw      75.38
       ewr      19.55
dtype: float64

city1  city2
sfo    yyz      0.0
       yvr      0.0
       dfw      0.0
       ewr     -1.1
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I'm going to give this a go later on today. I've tried Kartik's solution so far. Will report back. Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.