# Subtracting from one column based on values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subtraction

```
df_1

product_name  amount   price
     a           1        1
     b           2        2
     c           3        3
     d           4        4

df_2
product_name  amount
     a           1    
     b           2
```

Here is Sample of two data frame in pandas.

I want to make it subtracted `amount` with `product_names`
like `a` product will be `amount` 0 and `b` product also amount 0... with `product_name` column value.

thx for your time

Comment: Instead of posting an image, you should copy and paste your code.

Comment: Please post your df in text form, pictures are _NOT_ helpful.

Comment: Also, please post what you've tried so far to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have

df_1

```
product_name | amount | price
     a           1        1
     b           2        2
     c           3        3
     d           4        4
```

df_2

```
product_name | amount
     a           1    
     b           2
```

You can use set_index to set product_name as index for both df_1 and df_2, then use subtract() with fill_value = 0 to maintain any values that are not present in both dataframes.

```
df_1.set_index('product_name').subtract(df_2.set_index('product_name'), fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

The code above yields

```
product_name  | amount | price
     a           0.0      1.0
     b           0.0      2.0
     c           3.0      3.0
     d           4.0      4.0
```

The question is quite similar to [subtracting two dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987908/subtracting-two-dataframes)

Comment: You don't need to keep setting the index, if you just subtract the values. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46536055/4909087

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ The index is very necessary for proper alignment.

Answer (score 5):

**Option 1**
Taking advantage of your data using `df.isin`:

```
mask = a.product_name.isin(b.product_name)
a.loc[mask, 'amount'] = 0

a
  product_name  amount  price
0            a       0      1
1            b       0      2
2            c       3      3
3            d       4      4
```

---

**Option 2**
`set_index` + `reindex` + `subtract`. Slightly more robust, doesn't set to `0`:

```
b = b.set_index('product_name').reindex(a.product_name).fillna(0)
a.amount -= b.amount.values

a
  product_name  amount  price
0            a     0.0      1
1            b     0.0      2
2            c     3.0      3
3            d     4.0      4
```

Comment: Option 1 only works for a very specific case. Option 2 is nice.

Comment: @TedPetrou Yes, exactly. The first option works under a certain assumption. And thank you!

Comment: The -= for subtraction and the single use of set_index() with reindex blew my mind, very nice.

Answer (score 0):

You could also merge and then do subtraction

```
df = df1.merge(df2,how='left',on='product_name',suffixes=('','R'))
df.amount = df.amount - df.amountR.fillna(0)

  product_name  amount  price  amountR
0            a     0.0      1      1.0
1            b     0.0      2      2.0
2            c     3.0      3      NaN
3            d     4.0      4      NaN
```