# Mathematical operations between 2 similar dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, math

Two dataframes look like so and a new dataframe is created by subtracting all values in df2 from df1. The date is data type object and the other columns are data type float64.

```
df1

date  c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
1/17   5  5  5  5  5
2/17   5  5  5  5  5
3/17   5  5  5  5  5
4/17   5  5  5  5  5
5/17   5  5  5  5  5

df2

date  c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
1/17   1  1  1  1  1
2/17   1  1  1  1  1
3/17   1  1  1  1  1
4/17   1  1  1  1  1
5/17   1  1  1  1  1

new_df

date  c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
1/17   4  4  4  4  4
2/17   4  4  4  4  4
3/17   4  4  4  4  4
4/17   4  4  4  4  4
5/17   4  4  4  4  4
```

Comment: `df1 - df2` ...

Comment: Only detail is to make sure `date` in the index

Comment: Possible duplicate of [subtracting two dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987908/subtracting-two-dataframes)

Comment: Problem was the index, silly oversight! Thanks rafaelc